# MongoDB, $text with projection score meta seems to be broken

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to apply projection to a score based text search while maintaining the score value.

Seems to be broken.

The following does not maintain the score property.

```
export const searchUsers = async (searchTerm: string): Promise<UserLight[]> => {
    const nGrams = createEdgeNGrams(searchTerm);
    const projection = { ...userLightProjection, ...{ score: 1 } };
    const users = await UserModel.find(
        {
            $text: {
                $search: nGrams,
            },

            // TODO Potentially very slow; test on 3m users.
            // TODO Look into replacing with $text
            // or: [
            //     { username: new RegExp(searchTerm, "i") }, //
            //     { phoneNumber: new RegExp(searchTerm, "i") },
            // ],
        },
        { score: { $meta: "textScore" } },
        {
            // TODO: Score is not reserved..
            projection,
        }
        // userLightProjection
    )
        // .sort({ lastPlatformActionIso: -1 })
        .limit(50);

    // @ts-ignore
    return users;
};
```

Comment: can you explain what is broken here? FYI, you can pass projection in the second argument only of `find({ query param: 1  }, { field: 1, field: 2 })`, you have passed projection in both 2nd and 3rd argument.

Comment: Yes, because I want to show "score" which is related to $text searches. How can I do that with projection?

Comment: you did correct but, add your projection fields in the second argument with the score field, check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DnWGlDOYFOg).

Comment: I did that, and it didn't include the score still.

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb server? and which npm and version you are using?